# jQuery: change part of child's class name when parent's class changes

Tags: jquery, class, replace, parent-child

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="settings-choose">
    <a href="#setting1" class="setting-tab">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon setting1-off"></div>
            <div class="label">Setting 1</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#setting2" class="setting-tab">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="icon setting2-off"></div>
            <div class="label">Setting 2</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <!-- more .setting-tab elements -->
</div>
```

Whenever I click on one of the `.setting-tab` elements, I want to:

1. Add the class `.selected` to that `.setting-tab` element (and remove it from the others)
2. Replace the "`-off`" part of the class on its child `.icon` element with "`-on`" (and flip all of the others to "`-off`")

I can do #1 successfully, but not #2. Here's what I have:

```
$("#settings-choose .setting-tab").click(function(){
    $("#settings-choose .setting-tab").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    $("#settings-choose .setting-tab").each(function(){
        var icon = $(this).find(".icon"),
            state = icon.attr("class");

        if (!($(this).hasClass("selected"))){
            state.replace("-on", "-off");
        } else {
            state.replace("-off", "-on");
        }
    });
});
```

This correctly adds the `.selected` class to whichever `.setting-tab` element was clicked and removes it from the others...

```
<a href="#setting1" class="setting-tab selected">...</a>
<a href="#setting2" class="setting-tab">...</a>
```

But the class of the `.icon` element doesn't change...

```
<a href="#setting1" class="setting-tab selected">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="icon setting1-off"></div>
        <div class="label">Setting 1</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

I don't get any errors in the console, just...it doesn't change.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is you forgot the assign value for class just replacing a text in the variable.

```
    if (!($(this).hasClass("selected"))){
            icon.attr("class", state.replace("-on", "-off"));
        } else {
            icon.attr("class", state.replace("-off", "-on"));
        }
```

but you can make other changes to for example

```
$("#settings-choose .setting-tab").removeClass("selected");
```

instead

```
$("#settings-choose .selected").removeClass("selected");
```

Comment: Perfect! I see, `.replace()` just changes the text of the class name, but doesn't actually assign it back as the *value*. Thanks!